# Blazor - InputCheckbox: checking boxes based on what's in a database table

Tags: list, checkbox, blazor, checkboxlist, blazor-editform

I'm trying to prepopulate checkboxes based on numbers included in a database table. For example, the table entries could include:

| USER ID | ITEM ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 54 |

On my page, I would want to fill out the checkboxes based on the user entered. So user 1 would be (without the pretty Blazor UI of course):

| Item Name | Checkboxes |
| --- | --- |
| Dog(4) | X |
| Cat(5) | X |
| Rabbit(6) |  |
| Goat(10) | X |
| Llama(54) |  |

When the page opens I would want the items checked to match what's in the database. I'm hoping I can somehow get that to work by getting the list of numbers from the object item ids (4, 5, and 10 in the example).

I know how to handle Blazor check boxes with booleans and event handlers but am not sure how to base it off a list.

Comment: This is not what you would normally want to do with checkboxes. Why not use a list? In any event, if you did go with checkboxes you'd probably have to have all of them on the page, then loop through your items and make the appropriate ones checked.

Comment: I was using a list. Looping through them is what I ended up doing. I think my challenge was that I'd never done it dynamically before. Suryateja KONDLA's answer below is basically what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model in your Blazor app that represents the items and whether they are checked or not. For example:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize Models with Database Data

```
List<ItemModel> items = new List<ItemModel>
{
    new ItemModel { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "Dog" },
    new ItemModel { ItemId = 5, ItemName = "Cat" }
};

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (userSelectedItems.Contains(item.ItemId))
    {
        item.IsChecked = true; // Compare where "X"
    }
}
```

Or u can store the "X" in model and compare

Bind Checkboxes to Models

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="item.IsChecked">@item.ItemName (@item.ItemId)
}
```